# Unable to copy files from file system to IntelliJ IDEA 10.5

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-plugin, copy-paste, explorer

I have just started using IntelliJ IDEA.I am really novice to this IDE, so please bear if my question sounds silly.

I am facing a problem regarding copying of files from OS's File explorer to IntelliJ Project.

I am using following versions:

**Operating System: Ubuntu v. 11.04

IntelliJ IDEA: v. 10.5.1

JDK: v. 1.6.0_27**

For e.g. in the following image I have created a project having a Maven module.

[image: Intellij IDEA Project Screenshot]

I am unable to copy a schema file (.xsd) on my file system into the folder *..../src/main/conf/vehAvailRate*.I tried out so many times but the file is not getting copied.Also I tried the **Synchronize** feature too but that too didn't helped.However when I open the project in file system and copy my desired schema file there ,IntelliJ IDEA relfects the change.

Am I doing something wrong or there is some other reason behind this behavior?

Thanks,
Jignesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such copy should be performed externally, using your favorite file manager. IDEA will refresh files under its project directory automatically.

If something goes wrong, check **idea.log** file in `~/.IntelliJIdea10/system/log` directory.